# recurrence relation of $x^p$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find the recurring relation of $x^p$.
$x$ is in the set of the real numbers and $p$ is in the set of natural numbers.

Comment: $x^{p+1}= x(x^p)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_p=x^p$ $$ \implies f_{p+1}=xf_p.$$

Comment: @toaster_fan, you forgot about your problem!